# Storing multiple structures in gen_server state

Tags: erlang

How does one store multiple structures/items in a gen_server's state?

I want to store a reference to an ets table, as well as a queue and a counter(integer).

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A gen_server's state is just an arbitrary erlang term. Use whatever is most convenient (a record, a tuple, a list, a dict, whatever)

Answer (score 9):

Use a record?

```
-record(state, {table, queue, counter}).
```

Comment: Ok thanks, this is a noob question but how do I then set those values when the server is started?

Comment: `State = #state{table=Table, queue=Queue, counter=Counter}.`

Comment: And you update fields with `NewState = State#state{counter=NewCounter}`.